# Blind signing when trying to send USDT over Arbitrum network

Tags: ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, evm, abi, arbitrum

I am trying to send USDT ERC20 token through arbitrum network and all things go well until i want to personally sign it using my hardware wallet. seems like the ABI is wrong or corrupt as i get bling signing transaction message.

has anyone come across this before or does any one know off the shelf solution for issues like this? The Dapp i am building is having issues when trying to send USDT from arbitrum network even when i am using ABI provided by arbiscan.

Any suggestions or resources would be appreciated.

Thanks Heaps.

Tried sending USDT token through arbitrum network, can send it from browser extension wallet but when i try to send it from a hardware wallet, i get blind signing error